# FileUpload to upload image fail to save the image, but no error message displayed

Tags: php, image, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm using Yii2 basic. It doesn't seems like anything's wrong, no error message displayed, but why did my image didn't upload? The rest (title, content etc) get uploaded through the form,though

This is my model's rule and related method:

```
public $image;

 public function init(){
   Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::$app->basePath . '/uploads/batam/';
   Yii::$app->params['uploadUrl'] = Yii::$app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/uploads/batam/';
    }

 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title', 'content'], 'required'],
            [['content'], 'string'],
            [['created_at', 'updated_at','image'], 'safe'],
            [['image'], 'file','extensions'=>'jpg,png,jpeg'],
            [['title'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    public function getImageFile() 
    {
        return isset($this->image) ? Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'].$this->image : null;
    }

  public function uploadImage() {
     $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($this, 'image');
     if (empty($image)) {
            return false;
     }
     $this->image = $image->name;
        return $image;
     }
```

This is my controller

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new News();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) )
         {
           // process uploaded image file instance                    
            $image = $model->uploadImage();
                if($model->validate())
                {
                    if($model->save())
                        { 
                        // upload only if valid uploaded file instance found
                        if ($image !== false) 
                            {
                                $path = $model->getImageFile();
                                $image->saveAs($path);
                            }
                             return $this->redirect(['view', 'id'=>$model->id]);
                        }
                }
                        else{echo " validation is failed";}
         } 
        else{   
                     return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                         ]);
            }
    }
```

This is the form

```
echo $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
    'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
    'pluginOptions' => [['previewFileType' => 'any']]
]);
```

I had included the `enctype` also at the beginning of the form
`<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]);`

At this point  inside the `if ($image !== false)` part of the controller , the `$image` and `$path` to be saved-as contains a seemingly correct path.

This is my $path : `C:\xampp\htdocs\gbia/uploads/batam/test image 1-01.jpg` and my $image also contain the object (not null). This is the var_dump of my $image :

```
object(yii\web\UploadedFile)#179 (5) { ["name"]=> string(19) "test image 1-01.jpg" ["tempName"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php3199.tmp" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["size"]=> int(925184) ["error"]=> int(0) }
```

I think something wrong with the saveAs(), but I can't figure it out. Had googled around, look on stackoverflow and tutorials but I still can't find any answer. Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: Does the path exists?

Comment: @SyakurRahman Yes, it does. I just checked it, the image actually get uploaded in the folder specified in the path, but somehow it doesn't save the file name to my database. It's quite strange though, I tried `echo $model->image` (`image` is the column of my database model where I stored the uploaded file name) right after the `saveAs()` line being executed, it does echoed out my file name. But I checked in my phpmyadmin it's empty.

Comment: So I tried : 
```
if ($image !== false) 
                            {
                                $path = $model->getImageFile();
                                $image->saveAs($path);
echo $model->image;exit();
                            }
```
And it does return the file name. But I checked in my phpmyadmin there's nothing in the `image` column

Comment: Try adding image in your safe rule.

Comment: @SyakurRahman I added it and have updated my model rules in my first post. But still the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you perhaps try var_dump-ing $model->errors after $model->validate() / $model->save() and ensure that it is empty ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your model, you have declared $image as a public variable of the class, and not as a field in the database, if you want to store the data there, it will never work, as the public property that is temporary will have preference over the database column.

```
public $image;
```

So delete this field (If it is also in the db) or generate a new column name (I suggest by the name of path).

```
[['content', 'path'], 'string'],
```

Then you need to store the path, I don't see where are you doing that in the controller or class. I suggest you to add a field in the database with the "path" name and then do like this in the controller:

```
$path = $model->getImageFile();
$image->saveAs($path);
$model->path = $path . $image // You must store the full path plus the file name
$model->save(); // then you save the model again
```

Any doubt is welcome, I have example projects that I can show you if you are unable to see the light.

Comment: Yes, I found out that my public `$image` that handle my Uploaded File instance's rule was overlapping with my `image` column in the database, thus somehow got confused in the rules. I solved it by changing the `public $image` to something else and do the same adjustment in the `rules`, and it works. Thanks!